# "yotta" in Greek and Armenian

Tags: etymology, greek, armenian

The Armenian word for seven is "yotta", which sounds suspiciously similar to the Greek prefix for a factor of one septillion (though AIUI it comes from the ancient Greek word for eight, not seven). Is there evidence that these words are related, or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 6):

It is a coincidence.

The prefix "yotta-" is in no way Greek. It is a modern, invented, coinage, derived from Greek  ὀκτώ (okto) by a very roundabout and idiosyncratic route.

Armenian յոթ (yot') derives from Old Armenian եօթն (eot'n), older  եւթն (ewtʿn), ultimately from IndoEuropean *septḿ̥

See Wiktionary [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yotta-) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%B5%D5%B8%D5%A9#Armenian)